# R: Painfully slow read performance using RODBC & SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, r, database, performance, rodbc

I am new to R but am interested in using Shiny to create dynamic charts using data stored in a SQL Server database.  To enable interactivity, I want to bring in the raw data from the database and perform calculations within `R` rather than have the database summarize the data.

I am able to connect to the database using `RODBC`, execute a query, and receive results in a `data.frame`.  However, the read time in `R` is about 12x longer than than the same query executed in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).  SSMS takes ~600 ms, whereas `R` takes about 7.6 seconds.  My question is whether I am doing something wrong, or is `R` just really slow with database access?  And if so, are there faster alternatives (e.g. writing the database output to  a file and reading the file)?

Some information about the query that may help:  The query retrieves about 250K rows with 4 columns.  The first column is a date and the other three are numeric values.  The machine running `R` and SSMS is a high-end Win 7 workstation with 32GB of memory.  The `R` command that I am running is:

```
system.time(df <- sqlQuery(cn, query))
```

which returns:

```
user  system elapsed
7.17   0.01   7.58
```

Interestingly, it appears that the data transfer from SQL to my machine is fast, but that `R` is busy doing things internally for several seconds before returning  the `data.frame`.  I see this because network utilization spikes in the first second and almost immediately returns to near 0.  Then several seconds later, the `R` `data.frame` returns.

Comment: Pretty sure it's just that slow, we evaluated it a while back and decided to go another route then using RODBC, it's just way to slow except for very simple queries.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would try RJDBC
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RJDBC/RJDBC.pdf

with these drivers https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724.aspx

```
library(RJDBC)
drv <- JDBC("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver","/sqljdbc4.jar") 
con <- dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:sqlserver://server.location", "username", "password")
dbGetQuery(con, "select column_name from table")
```

Comment: Thank you! This absolutely solved the problem. Elapsed time dropped to 0.84 seconds as a result.

Comment: Can we use RJDBC in windows to speed up the process?

Comment: Yes. JDBC (Java Database Connectivity) can be used on OSX/Linux/Windows

Comment: JDBC(driverClass = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver", classPath = "~/HTS/Data/R/Functions/Driver/sqljdbc41.jar")
Error in .jfindClass(as.character(driverClass)[1]) : class not found

Any  idea what is causing the problem ?

Comment: Im having issues trying to use RJDBC as well.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71578602/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-via-rjdbc

Answer (score 2):

I would make sure that your R timezone - `Sys.setenv(TZ='GMT')` set to GMT for example - is same as the time zone of the SQL server from where you are pulling data. It could be that the date column is taking a long time to be interpreted especially if it has a timestamp.

RJDBC will run quicker because it converts date to character and everything else to numeric. RODBC will try to preserve the data type of the SQL table.

Comment: What if both R and SQL server have the same TZ but queries are still performing really slow?