# R Quickest way to import large MSSQL data tables

Tags: sql-server, r, import, odbc, rjdbc

I am looking for the utmost quickest way to import an MSSQL data table into R.

I currently use:

```
ch <- odbcConnect("Table1", uid="***", pwd="***")
system.time(TransactionFrame <- sqlFetch(ch, "V_Transactions_Extended"))
odbcClose(ch)
```

There are +/- 5 million rows and about 80 columns. This takes about 60min. I appreciate that this is a function of many things, including network traffic.

Is there a quicker way to import this? I am happy to try any sort of work around; for e.g. copy the MSSQL table onto my C:\ first and then some other quicker import function. Step by step spoon-fulls for me please!

I have also tried RJDBC as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30943748/r-painfully-slow-read-performance-using-rodbc-sql-server) which is not better.

Thanks in advance.