# RJDBC Error when trying to create a connection to SQL Server

Tags: java, r, sql-server, jdbc, rjdbc

I have been using RODBC to do all sort of sql queries, but I ended up having to deal with a query that happens to take a painfully amount of time compared to when I run the query in SQL Server.

I found in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30943748/r-painfully-slow-read-performance-using-rodbc-sql-server) that `RJDBC` has a better performace, so I decided to try it out.

I ended up intalling Java (both jre and jdk), setted up the Paths and the Drivers of JDBC.

I have no problem getting the driver I guess, since I got no error.

```
drv <- JDBC(classPath = "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft JDBC DRIVER 11.2 for SQL Server\\sqljdbc_11.2\\enu\\mssql-jdbc-11.2.0.jre8.jar")
```

But when I try to create the connection I get the following error

```
conn <- dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.7.303", "my_user", "my_password")
```

> Error in dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.7.303", "my_user",  :
> Unable to connect JDBC to jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.7.303
> JDBC ERROR: The driver couldn't establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target". ClientConnectionId:8902e2fd-d90e-47c8-8aed-7ea373c9245d

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: Have you tried adding `TrustServerCertificate=false;` to your connection properties? JDBC 10.2 introduced a breaking change, making `Encrypt=true;` a default parameter (previously it was `Encrypt=false;`), causing encrypted connections to SQL Server instances. This is problematic because Microsoft SQL Server installs with self-signed (read: untrusted) certificates by default, thus causing the error message that you are seeing. Ref: [JDBC Driver 10.2 for SQL Server Released](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/jdbc-driver-10-2-for-sql-server-released/ba-p/3100754).

Comment: Use the DNS name rather than the IP address. Do you actually have SQL Server set up with a valid SSL certificate?

Comment: AlwaysLearning: do you mean: `dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.7.303; TrustServerCertificate=false;", "my_user", "my_password")` ?